# ¿Cuál es la diferencia de una variable declarada en un bucle a una declarada fuera de el (una función)?

Tags: java, variables, scope

estoy haciendo un programa muy sencillo que obtiene el factorial de un número sin recursividad, pero me encontré con el siguiente caso, probablemente no sé la respuesta por no conocer las bases (lleva un tiempo que no escribo código, debería de saberlas aunque no haya escrito código en un tiempo):
[image: Este es el código, ignoren los comentarios si es necesario]
El código funciona, pero no entiendo por qué al declarar e inicializar la variable dentro del bucle for, el código hace lo que se supone que debería de pasar, o sea: factorial = factorial(= 1) * contador(= número)-1. Pero si declaro e inicializo factorial en el método main: contador = 4 * 1 = 4 * 3 = 12 * 2 = 24 * 1 = 24. Si contador es igual a número, imagino que factorial = contador = numero = 4, pero cuando el flujo entra en el bucle for, el factorial vale el valor ingresado por el usuario (número) y así se queda, con ese valor e ignora el operador de decremento, como si contador fuera igual a 5 (en los paréntesis) y número en factorial.
En resumen: una variable tiene el mismo valor, pero funcionan como si fueran dos variables separadas, con valores diferentes.
Gracias.

Comment: Mark, lo mejor es que coloques el texto del codigo, no utilices imagenes de codigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El java los valores primitivos,  como int, double, etc, no son objetos por lo que al hacer int contador=número, cada variable apunta a una dirección de memoria distinta y las operaciones que hagas en una no afecta a la otra.
Si fueran objetos, como los tipos Integer, si que al usar el = ambas variables apuntarían a la misma dirección de memoria y las operaciones sobre ambas variables si que afectarían al mismo objeto.